# EJB 3: Accessing a stateful session bean from an application client

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, stateful-session-bean, application-client

I am having some trouble accessing a stateful session bean (SFSB) from an application client. I am using JBoss 5.0.1.GA. The application client and the EJBs are both packaged in an EAR which deploys and I have other application clients which work without problems. So far, I have only used stateless session beans (SLSBs), but as far as I unterstand it, the differences between SLSBs and SFSBs should not affect how they can be accessed from an application client.

The structure of the classes/interfaces:

```
@Local public interface A {...}

@Stateless public class ABean implements A {...}

@Remote public interface B {...}

@Stateful public class BBean implements B {
    @EJB private A anInstanceOfA;

    @PostConstruct private void init() {
        this.anInstanceOfA.someMethod();
    }
}
```

The application client is run via the "appclient-launcher" as described in ["How to use an application client in JBoss 5"](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/HowtouseanapplicationclientinJBoss-5). Doing the lookup of "BBean" works fine until someMethod() on the (local) ABean is called during the execution of init(). During that call, the container throws an InvalidStateException("Local call: security context is null") (as the root cause). When I change the stateful bean to a stateless bean, everything works fine (except, of course, that the state is not preserved). Interestingly, I can use the exact same SFSB from a web application (in a JSF managed-bean) just fine.

Am I doing something wrong? How am I supposed to use a SFSB from an application client?

I have not found anything useful about this particular problem so far. The exception is mentioned in a similar context in [[#JBAS-4317] Security Context over the invocation](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-4317), but considering that it is marked as done and is fixed in JBoss 5.0.0.Beta3, it seems not to be the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I'd still like to know why my original setup it works perfectly for stateless session beans but not for stateful session beans, here is the solution I found:

The web-application that is also packaged in the EAR does its authentication via JAAS. For this I have configured a security domain in the JBoss login-config.xml, which looks like this:

```
<application-policy name="My-SD">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity">guest</module-option>
            <module-option name="dsJndiName">java:/myDS</module-option>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery">SELECT PASSWORD FROM LOGIN WHERE LOGIN = ? AND STATUS > 0</module-option>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery">SELECT ROLE, 'Roles' FROM USER_ROLE WHERE LOGIN = ?</module-option>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

I have used this security domain in the web-application's jboss-web.xml as well as in the EJB-project's jboss.xml, even though I actually only use it in the web-app (the EJBs are accessible without authentication).

To solve the problem with accessing the SFSB, I just had to remove my security domain from the jboss.xml in the EJB-project. This then makes JBoss use the default security domain which seems to do the right thing and my application client finally can access and use the SFSB.

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be found in the [EJB 3.0 Core Specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr220/index.html), section 12.4. There it says

> Lifecycle callback interceptor methods are invoked in an unspecified transaction and security context.

hth,
- martin

Comment: Interesting information. Though, I am not sure how this explains the behaviour, especially as it "works" in a stateless bean and the problem only occurs when I used my own security domain. Anyway, since I have nothing to do with the project anymore and have not done any Java EE development since then, I am not really motivated to find out how this stuff actually works. Thanks anyway!